# How can bind hidden input value to parent component in blazor dotnetcore 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I new to blazor. I have hidden input with a specific value bind send to a parent component. I went ahead with [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#child-to-parent-binding-with-chained-bind)

Child Component is (name is MyControl):

```
  <div>
        @foreach (var result in this.Results)
        {
            if (result.IsFinal)
            {

                        @(Text= result.Items[0].Transcript)
            <input type="hidden" @oninput="OnTextChanged" value="Text" />
            }
            else
            {
                <img class="embed-responsive" style="height: 50px; width: auto;" src="https://gifdownload.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/blue-loader-gif-3.gif"/>

            }
        }
    </div>
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }

    private Task OnTextChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = e.Value.ToString();
        return TextChanged.InvokeAsync(Text);
    }
}
```

and Parent Comonent is:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <MyControl @bind-Text="text" />
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="http://blazor.net" target="_blank" class="ml-md-auto">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        <CascadingValue Value="text">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>

    </div>
</div>
@code{

    private string text;

}
```

and usages for example in index component:

```
@page "/"



@if (text != null)
{
    <p>
        @text
    </p>
}



@code
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

note: I don't use a keyboard for wite text. input filling from   `@(Text= result.Items[0].Transcript)`.
totally I want to give text from a child and send to parent but I don't show the text (For this purpose, I used a hidden input) , after that send to all components by CascadingValue parameter, but not working and no errors, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code: `<input type="hidden" @oninput="OnTextChanged" value="Text" />`
results in one way data-binding from the variable (Text property) to the control, but not the other way around, as no input UI is performed, and no input event is triggered to reflect this. Which is why the OnTextChanged handler is never called and the TextChanged 'delegate' is never invoked, and thus the parent component never gets a value from the Child Component( MyControl ).

To see that the rest of the code functions well, change 'hidden' to 'text', and type into the text box. This will trigger the input event, and the whole process will work.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but you should look for a solution without a hidden input that cannot get any input, and thus cannot trigger events, etc.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I don't use a keyboard for wite text. input filling from   `@(Text= result.Items[0].Transcript)`

Comment: Did you read my answer ? Do you understand what I'm saying ? Input event can only occurs when the tad element is visible, and the user type text into it. This is why you cannot use input hidden element the way you use it. It can never trigger the input event. You have to look for another means to attain your objective.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide it with CSS.

I do the same thing in my open source project BlazorChat.

The way I do it is real simple with CSS:

CSS Class

```
.className
{
    position: fixed;        
    left: -200px;
    top: -200px;
}
```

Adjust based on the size of your object

Here is a working example:

Code
https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorChat

Or even a live site if you want to visit:

https://blazorchat.com

[image]

Comment: I don't use a keyboard for wite text. input filling from   `@(Text= result.Items[0].Transcript)`

Comment: display: none, would be a much better way to hide it.

Comment: I realize I'm commenting on an old-ish answer but this approach and the `display: none;` approach are not good for WCAG and 508 standards.  If you disable CSS or use a screen reader your "hidden" textbox is visible again.  The only safe way to do this is with the hidden attribute on the input element as suggested in the accepted answer